# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout - Unexpected layout with fractionalWidth width and self sizing cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

## Requirement

I am trying to make a CollectionView section that has 1 large item then 4 half-width items below like this:

[image]

Each cell will contain labels that support multiline text or variable length with dynamic type support.

## Approach

I have written the following compositional layout code which constructs 3 groups. A `fullWidthGroup` contains a single item that is full width (item 1). A `halfWidthGroup` will hold 2 items per "row" and a main outer group `group` which is made up of 1 fullWidthGroup and 2 halfWidthGroups.

```
    private let compositionalLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(sectionProvider: { (sectionIndex, environment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
        let margin: CGFloat = 8
        
        // Items
        let fullWidthItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .estimated(50))
        let fullWidthItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: fullWidthItemSize)
        fullWidthItem.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: margin, bottom: 0, trailing: margin)

        let halfWidthItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5), heightDimension: .estimated(50))
        let halfWidthItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: halfWidthItemSize)
        halfWidthItem.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: margin, bottom: 0, trailing: margin)
        
        // Groups
        let fullWidthGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: fullWidthItemSize, subitems: [fullWidthItem])
        
        let halfWidthGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: halfWidthItemSize.heightDimension)
        let halfWidthGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: halfWidthGroupSize, subitems: [halfWidthItem])
        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .estimated(150))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [fullWidthGroup, halfWidthGroup, halfWidthGroup])
        group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(margin)
        
        // Section
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = margin
        
        return section
    })
```

This gives the desired result for basic cells that do not contain any constraints (to self size them).

[image]

## Problem

As soon as I create a cell that has constraints that can be used to correctly evaluate the size of the cell width of the cells is unexpectedly changed.

[image]

Resulting in the following layout.

[image]

## Expectation

I would expect the last 4 items to take up half the width but instead, they appear to be taking up less space. Item 1 which should be full width with an 8 point margin on each side seems to also be sized incorrectly with ~16 point margin on the trailing edge.

[image]

## Full Code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    private let compositionalLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(sectionProvider: { (sectionIndex, environment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
        let margin: CGFloat = 8
        
        // Items
        let fullWidthItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .estimated(50))
        let fullWidthItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: fullWidthItemSize)
        fullWidthItem.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: margin, bottom: 0, trailing: margin)

        let halfWidthItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5), heightDimension: .estimated(50))
        let halfWidthItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: halfWidthItemSize)
        halfWidthItem.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: margin, bottom: 0, trailing: margin)
        
        // Groups
        let fullWidthGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: fullWidthItemSize, subitems: [fullWidthItem])
        
        let halfWidthGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: halfWidthItemSize.heightDimension)
        let halfWidthGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: halfWidthGroupSize, subitems: [halfWidthItem])
        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .estimated(150))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [fullWidthGroup, halfWidthGroup, halfWidthGroup])
        group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(margin)
        
        // Section
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = margin
        
        return section
    })
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "BasicCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = compositionalLayout
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
    }
}
```

The BasicCollectionViewCell is created in a nib and contains a stack view (added to the contentView). The StackView is pinned to all edges with a priority of 1000. Inside the stackview is a label.